# How to hide the popup of Androids Voice Recognition, without using RecognitionListener

Tags: android, voice-recognition, recognizer-intent

After the latest 2 updates of the Google App, voice recognition experience in my app has worsened dramatically, because the microphone takes more than 5 seconds to stop recording after the user has stopped speaking.
This bug has been reported to Google, and they only fixed it partially in the last update (If I uninstall Google App updates and rollback my phone to the older Google app shipped with the phone everything works fine).

I am using the RecognitionListener approach.

This problem does not occur when I launch a RecognizerIntent voice recognition popup like this:

```
startActivityForResult(speechIntent, SPEECHRECON_CODE);
```

How can I hide that Voice Recognition dialog popup??

Comment: Are you using the SpeechRecognizer? Maybe this will do the better job for you? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html

Comment: You can't remove the popup when using the implementation as you demonstrate. Only the `SpeechRecognizer` I'm afraid.

Comment: @MartinPfeffer Thanks for the suggestion, I tried the SpeechRecognizer approach, but it takes around 5 seconds of silence to stop voice recognition automatically. This problem has been persisting since the last 2 updates of Google Apps. Apparently only the Popup Speech recognition option works properly :s